# Doing X when model is saved

Tags: django, orm, django-models, model, save

What's the correct way to do X when Django's model is saved? Let me try to explain it. :)

For example, I have model that is responsible for blog's articles. I want to use title field to generate slug field if it's not set already. It should happen just before model is saved. This is how I have achieved it at the moment.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.slug == '':
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Are there any other way to do it? Are other ways better than this, how?

Thanks in any advice!

Comment: the problem with this is if there is a unique constraint on slug for this model,  then you will have an issue

Comment: What's the problem to use `slugify(self.title)` in your code, and not save it in database? What happens if title is changed? Anyway - you can also use `django.db.models.signals.pre_save`

Comment: Tisho, I don't want to put business logic into view. It seems that signals are what I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate way is to override the `clean` method of your model:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.slug.strip() == '':
            self.slug = defaultfilters.slugify(self.title)

        super(Article, self).clean()
```

This method will be called before the model is saved, and before any uniqueness checks are done, so if there's an issue, it will still be caught.

You can read about model's clean method [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Answer (score 1):

I would build it into the input form and use a ModelAdmin or ModelForm.

Admin Form:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title', )}
```

ModelForm:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def clean_slug(self):
       if !self.cleaned_data['slug'] :
           self.cleaned_data['slug'] = slugify(self.title)
       return True
```

again in that clean_slug you may want to check to see if its unique first... and modify the slug to be unique if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use signals. Use the post save signal that comes with django. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/